# Do uri addresses vary for different android devices?

Tags: app-inventor

I have an App Inventor app that creates a file and then triggers another app (not App Inventor) to read that file using `Activity Starter` and feeding it the uri:

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/filename
```

Would that work on any android device (it works on mine)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic path to the file

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/filename
```

which will work for all Android devices.